# Check for whether a string contains any duplicate characters

Tags: beginner, c, strings

I am a new programmer and I want to know if I'm inheriting the right styles. I don't want to pick up any bad/amateur habits. Any advice would be much appreciated.

This is an `isUnique` function I wrote in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{   
    int x;
    char s1[] = "dog hi cobe!";
    x = isUnique(s1);
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}

isUnique(char* s1)
{
    char holder;
    int i;
    int j;

    if(s1 == NULL)
        return -1;

    for(i = 0; i < (strlen(s1) -1); i++)
    {
        holder = s1[i];
        for(j = i; j < (strlen(s1)-1); j++)
        {
            if(holder == s1[j+1])
            {
                if(holder == ' ')
                    continue;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And I'm going to say the run time complexity is \$O(n^2)\$, would I be correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Missing return type

This function declaration is missing the return type:

```
isUnique(char* s1)
```

Sure, the default return type is `int` in C,
but it would be better to just write it anyway for clarity.

#### Use boolean

C99 has a `bool` type with `true` and `false` values,
which you can get from this `#include`:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

It would be better to rewrite `isUnique` to return a `bool`.
Even though, this will mean giving up the special value -1 for the `NULL` input case. But that doesn't seem so bad. A name like "is*" is commonly expected to return a boolean. If you really need a function that can handle the `NULL` case, you could create a wrapper function:

```
/* returns -1 on NULL input, 0 if not unique, 1 if unique */
int checkUnique(char* s1) {
    if (s1 == NULL) return -1;
    return isUnique(s1);
}
```

Note that the `bool` return value of `isUnique` will be converted to `int`, so that `false` is 0 and `true` is 1.

#### Avoid repeated calculations

You call `strlen(s1)` twice:

> ```
> for(i = 0; i < (strlen(s1) -1); i++)
> {
>     holder = s1[i];
>     for(j = i; j < (strlen(s1)-1); j++)
> ```

It would be better to call it once, store in a variable and reuse.

#### Time complexity

As you suspected, the time complexity of your algorithm is \$O(n^2)\$:
all characters are compared with all other.

You could improve that to \$O(n)\$ by using extra storage, the size of the alphabet.
You could create an array of `bool`, representing if a character was already seen or not:

- All values are initialized to `false`
- For character in the input, check if it was seen

  - If it was seen, return `false`
  - If it was not seen, mark it now (set value in the `bool` array to `true`)
- If the end of the string is reached, return `true`

Something like this:

```
bool isUnique(char * string) {
    int len = strlen(string);

    bool seen[256];
    memset(seen, false, sizeof(seen));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = string[i];
        if (seen[c]) {
            return false;
        }
        seen[c] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

#### Printing the result

This will print a 0 or 1:

> ```
> int x;
> char s1[] = "dog hi cobe!";
> x = isUnique(s1);
> printf("%d", x);
> ```

It would be more informative to print the strings that was tested, and "false"/"true" instead of 0/1:

```
char s1[] = "dog hi cobe!";
printf("%s -> %s\n", s1, isUnique(s1) ? "true" : "false");
```

#### Usability

It would be more interesting if the program took the strings from the command line, instead of using hardcoded values, for example:

```
void printWithResult(char* string) {
    printf("%s -> %s\n", string, isUnique(string) ? "true" : "false");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {   
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printWithResult(argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I learned so much through that! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Also, I'm don't quite understand the time complexity reduction method you described. Can you please give me further clarification/example?

Comment: Lastly, to pass in the arguments from the command line, why are we also creating an int parameter and why is the second parameter a double pointer rather than a single pointer?

Comment: I added an example implementation of an \$O(n)\$ algorithm. As for the `int main(int argc, char ** argv)` signature, that's standard, you can learn about it in any C tutorial about command line argument parsing

Answer (score 5):

The combination of conditions

```
        if(holder == s1[j+1])
        {
            if(holder == ' ')
                continue;
```

makes the whole inner loop void if `holder == ' '`, so you may save scanning the string much earlier:

```
for(i = 0; i < (strlen(s1) -1); i++)
{
    holder = s1[i];
    if(holder == ' ')
        continue;
    for(j = i; j < (strlen(s1)-1); j++)
    {
        if(holder == s1[j+1])
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally you can simplify the code a bit if you start the `j` loop one char ahead:

```
int len = strlen(s1);
for(i = 0; i < len-1; i++)
{
    holder = s1[i];
    if(holder == ' ')
        continue;
    for(j = i+1; j < len; j++)
    {
        if(holder == s1[j])
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

For such a relatvely small symbol set (256 possible values of `char` type, max 255 of which can appear in the string) you can just arrange an array of counters:

```
int counter[256];
```

reset it to zeros:

```
for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    counter[i] = 0;
```

or, based on the known array of `int` memory layout:

```
memset(counter, 0, 256*sizeof(int));
```

and count occurences of each character (up to two)

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++)
{
    if(s1[i] != ' ')
        if(++counter[(unsigned char)s1[i]] > 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
}
return 1;
```

This will test your string in linear time (plus constant time for preparing `counter[]` array).

Comment: by using the keyword "continue" does that make the program skip the rest of the block of code in that loop(i.e. the inner for loop)?

Comment: Yes, it forces the re-iteration of a loop. More precisely, if the body of a loop is a compound statement, that is a block enclosed in `{ }` braces, then the `continue` instruction behaves as a `goto` to the closing brace. If the loop body is not a block, `continue` passes the control to evaluation of the loop controlling expression in a `while` loop or to the third expression in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling, always enable all the warnings.

(for gcc, at a minimum use: -Wall -Wextra -pedantic I also use -Wconversion -std=c99 )

the result will be:

1. implicit declaration of function: isUnique
2. return type defaults to 'int' for function: isUnique
3. comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions for line: `for(i = 0; i < (strlen(s1) -1); i++)`
4. comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions for line: `for(j = i; j < (strlen(s1)-1); j++)`.
5. Note: `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`
6. there is no need to call `strlen()` at all!  instead use something like: `for(j = i; s1[j]; j++)` which will exit the loop upon encountering the NUL string terminator byte.
7. when possible, data/variables should be localized to where they are used.  so these lines can be eliminated: `int i;
   int j;` by writing the loop similar to: `for(size_t j = i; s1[j]; j++)`
8. there is no need for the `char holder;` line.
9. the 'j' variable is being started with `j = i`  is should be `j = i+1`
10. Stopping the search because a space  is encountered is not correct.
11. do not #include headers those contents are not being used.
12. use strategic comments so the reader, (and you in 6 months)  will know what is being done in the code
13. always use function prototypes so the compiler will not be using some 'default' values/types (and in latest C standard, the defaults are changed thereby causing the compiler to raise warnings)

Here is a suggested implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>

// prototypes
int isUnique(char* s1);

int main( void )
{
    int x;
    char *s1 = "dog hi cobe!";
    x = isUnique(s1);
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
} // end function: main

int isUnique(char* s1)
{

    if( !s1 )
    { 
        // indicate no string passed
        return -1;
    }

    for( size_t i = 0; s1[i]; i++ )
    {
        for( size_t j = i+1; s1[j]; j++ )
        {
            if( s1[i] == s1[j] )
            { 
                // indicate characters are not unique
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    // indicate characters are unique
    return 1;
} // end function: isUnique
```

Comment: Thank you for all those helpful suggestions! I had one quick question. For your 6th suggestion, how exactly is the for loop behaving by writing s1[j] as the second parameter into the for loop? I am asking this for references (b/c I do not see a conditional statement). What exactly would is the implicit condition stated there?

Comment: the second parameter of a `for()` statement only looks at the result as being 'true' (non zero) or 'false' (zero)  so the 's1[j]' (and 's1[j]) is looking at the byte selected by the parameter: 's1[i]'.   If that byte contains '\0' then the condition is 'false'  otherwise it is 'true'.  when the 'condition' is 'false', then the loop exits.

Comment: here is a quick summary of the syntax for the `for(expresion1; expression2; expression3)` statement:  
    expression1 - Initialisese variables.
    expression2 - Condtional expression, as long as this condition is true, loop will keep executing.
    expression3 - expression3 is the modifier which may be simple increment of a variable.